# Can you send an email with body and attachment programatically on Android & iOS?

Tags: android, ios, email

I know you can send an email programatically on Android with everything prefilled like this:

```
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent. ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(png));
    emailIntent.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_intent_name)));
```

I want to confirm if you can do the same on iOS. And if both platforms take you to their default email client or if it's possible to do anything in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to confirm if you can do the same on iOS

Yes.

> And if both platforms take you to their default email client

Not to default email client, but Android gives the user an option to choose a client capable of handling the action. In iOS, you use the MessageUI Framework which gives the `MFMailComposeViewController` which is an in-app mail composer.

> if it's possible to do anything in the background

If you mean to send the email without user intervention, of course it is possible. But you won't be able to send from the email account configured for the user.

Comment: "If you mean to send the email without user intervention, of course it is possible. But you won't be able to send from the email account configured for the user." Are you able to give me an example how to do it? That you in advance!

Comment: You can either use a pre-configured SMTP server (check https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage) or use an email delivery service like SendGrid (check https://sendgrid.com/blog/send-email-in-ios-with-new-sendgrid-library/)

Answer (score 3):

Send mail on iOS, here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender {
    //email subject
    NSString * subject = @"send mail for iOS";
    //email body
    NSString * body = @"Hello";
    //recipient(s)
    NSArray * recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"account@domain.com", nil];

    //create the MFMailComposeViewController
    MFMailComposeViewController * composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [composer setSubject:subject];
    [composer setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];
    //[composer setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES]; //if you want to send an HTML message
    [composer setToRecipients:recipients];

    //get the filepath from resources
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ball" ofType:@"png"];

    //read the file using NSData
    NSData * fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    // Set the MIME type
    /*you can use :
     - @"application/msword" for MS Word
     - @"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" for PowerPoint
     - @"text/html" for HTML file
     - @"application/pdf" for PDF document
     - @"image/jpeg" for JPEG/JPG images
     */
    NSString *mimeType = @"image/png";

    //add attachement
    [composer addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:mimeType fileName:filePath];

    //present it on the screen
    [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled"); break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved"); break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent"); break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]); break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```